# Matching a list of dictionaries A to list C with list B having common properties of A and C in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have three lists of dictionaries, A, B and C. They look like:

```
A = [{propA1: valueA1}, {propA1: valueA2}, ...]
B = [{propB1: valueB1, propB2: valueB2}, {propB1: valueB3, propB2: value4}, ...]
C = [{propC1: valueC1}, {propC1: valueC2}, ...]
```

`propA1` and `propB1` are same properties but different name, `propB2` and `propC1` are same properties as well.
However, `propA1` and `propB1` do not always have same values, but I am only interested in the "set intersect" of array `[valueA1, valueA2, ...]` and `[valueB1, valueB2, ...]`, here is the goal: **I want to return all `propB2` from `B` such that their `propB1` counterpart (in the same dictionary) match with `propA1` in A. Then I will use that `propB2` set to match with `propC1` in `C`.**

What I have tried:

```
propB2_match = set()
for elementB in B:
    for elementA in A:
        if elementB['propB1'] == elementA['propA1']:
            propB2_match(elementB['propB2'])            
            break
```

At the end of this loop, I have `propB2_match` containing all of `propB2` that I can use to match with `propC1`.
However, as you can see from the loop, this is an expensive `O(n^2)` loop. I am wondering if there is a way to handle this with `O(n)`? If not, is there any pythonic optimization can be done on it?

Note: I do not want to put it in a database and use relational database SQL to handle the join operation.

Comment: Can you read the section in bold again, this is not clear as you are stating that you want all propB2 that its propB1 match with probA1 (notice prop and prob) and then given what you say earlier why would valueB2 and valueB1 be releated?

Comment: You could basically implement "join". Create a new dict A' that maps `valueA1` to an element `{propA1: valueA1}`, and a new dict B' that maps `valueB1` to an element `{propB1: valueB1, propB2: valueB2}` and then use `itertools.groupBy` on the results

Comment: @PyNEwbie I updated my question.

Comment: @spiffman Can you elaborate this a bit more? What do you mean by "new dict A' that maps valueA1 to an element {propA1: valueA1}"?

Comment: @return0 I can make a more detailed post later, but I mean a dict that looks like `{valueA1: {propA1: valueA1}, valueA2: {propA1: valueA2}, ... }` and another that looks like `{valueB1: {propB1: valueB1, propB2: valueB2}, valueB2: {propB1: valueB3, propB2: value4}, ... }`. Essentially, you're keying by the value that you want to group by.

Comment: @return0 I ended up doing a slightly different way that is IMO a bit simpler than using groupby, see answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do a essentially do a JOIN on A and B where columns A['propA1'] == B['propB1'].

Here's one way using defaultdict that's O(len(A)+len(B)):

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = [{'pA1': 'vA1'}, {'pA1': 'vA2'}]
B = [{'pB1': 'vA1', 'pB2': 'vB2'}, {'pB1': 'vB3', 'pB2': 'v4'}]

# Key by the value you want to group on
kA = [(x['pA1'],x) for x in A]
kB = [(x['pB1'],x) for x in B]

# Combine the lists
kAB = kA+kB

# Map each unique key to a list of elements that have that key
results = defaultdict(list)
for x in kAB:
    results[x[0]].append(x[1])

for x in results:
    print results[x]
```

Outputs:

```
[{'pA1': 'vA2'}]
[{'pB1': 'vB3', 'pB2': 'v4'}]
[{'pA1': 'vA1'}, {'pB1': 'vA1', 'pB2': 'vB2'}]
```

At this point you could merge each list of dicts into a single dict or whatever you need, and use the result to JOIN with the third list C.